What is the difference between these two functions in x64 assembly?
I'm playing around with lower level stuff in C on Windows (x64) to try and learn low level concepts.  I ran across something I don't understand and just wonder if someone could explain something to me.  I admit I'm a novice here.
I have two lines of code that print out the address of functions, one from the windows API  (CreateFileW) and one from the same code files (addfunc).  I thought they'd be similar when I looked at the assembly, but one line uses 'mov' and one uses 'lea'.  Can anyone tell me how they are different?  And why?
    printf("%x\n", CreateFileW);
00007FF60365276C  mov         rdx,qword ptr [__imp_CreateFileW (07FF603663000h)]  
00007FF603652773  lea         rcx,[string "%x\n" (07FF60365BEA0h)]  
00007FF60365277A  call        printf (07FF603651208h)  
    printf("%x\n", addfunc);
00007FF60365277F  lea         rdx,[addfunc (07FF60365137Fh)]  
00007FF603652786  lea         rcx,[string "%x\n" (07FF60365BEA0h)]  
00007FF60365278D  call        printf (07FF603651208h)  


CreateFileW is imported from a dll.

You probably want to use %p to print a pointer, and cast the pointer to (void *).

One is from a DLL, the other from static code.

For whatever reason (somebody else can speak to particulars about Windows linking), the address of CreateFileW is not immediately available and has to be loaded from a memory location where it has been stored. This is not atypical of a dynamically linked library, where software to load parts of a programs manages address space during program execution. In contrast, addfunc appears to be statically linked, which allows the linker to “fix up” instructions that use its address. During the link, the address in the lea instruction is adjusted to provide the address of addfunc.
